# Matching values in two columns then based on that returning new value in R

Tags: r, loops, match

I have these columns in a data frame that look like:

```
combination  color_1  color_2

1_1          red       red
1_2          red       blue
1_3          red       green
1_4          red       yellow
2_1          blue      red
2_2          blue      blue
2_3          blue      green
2_4          blue      yellow
...
```

Based off matching the color_1 and color_2 values, I would like to be able to create new columns that outputs the result of the match. **There are certain specifications to this.**  For the first row where "red" and "red" are the same, the output in the new column (e.g. "Red-Only") should be a "1", and then "2" for every other match. Then, I would repeat this code but then picking up on matches where "blue" and "blue" occur, to output "1" in a next column (e.g. "Blue-Only") and "2" everywhere else. This goes for Yellow-only matches, Green-only matches, etc. So at the end I would have 4 extra columns depending on the condition.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: In column `color_1`, are the colors always grouped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ifelse.  If you have a lot looping would be a good idea

```
cols <- data.frame(
color_1=c("Red","Red","Red","Red","Blue","Blue","Blue","Blue"),
color_2=c("Red","Blue","Green","Yellow","Red","Blue","Green","Yellow")
) 

cols$redonly <- ifelse( cols$color_1 %in% "Red" & cols$color_2 %in% "Red" , 1 ,2 )
cols$Blueonly <- ifelse( cols$color_1 %in% "Blue" & cols$color_2 %in% "Blue" , 1 ,2 )
cols$greeonly <- ifelse( cols$color_1 %in% "Green" & cols$color_2 %in% "Green" , 1 ,2 )
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with your existing data:

```
df <- structure(list(combination = c("1_1", "1_2", "1_3", "1_4", "2_1", 
"2_2", "2_3", "2_4"), color_1 = c("red", "red", "red", "red", 
"blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"), color_2 = c("red", "blue", "green", 
"yellow", "red", "blue", "green", "yellow")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

  combination color_1 color_2
1         1_1     red     red
2         1_2     red    blue
3         1_3     red   green
4         1_4     red  yellow
5         2_1    blue     red
6         2_2    blue    blue
7         2_3    blue   green
8         2_4    blue  yellow
```

One solution would be to loop over your four color categories, checking for matches.

```
colors <- c('red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue')

matches <- lapply(colors, function(x) {
  out <- ifelse(with(df, color_1 == color_2 & color_1 == x), 1, 2)
  out
})
```

And then naming the results of this operation with your intended column names.

```
names(matches) <- paste(colors, 'only', sep = '_')
```

And finally, gluing the results together with the original data:

```
df.new <- cbind(df, as.data.frame(matches))

  combination color_1 color_2 red_only green_only yellow_only blue_only
1         1_1     red     red        1          2           2         2
2         1_2     red    blue        2          2           2         2
3         1_3     red   green        2          2           2         2
4         1_4     red  yellow        2          2           2         2
5         2_1    blue     red        2          2           2         2
6         2_2    blue    blue        2          2           2         1
7         2_3    blue   green        2          2           2         2
8         2_4    blue  yellow        2          2           2         2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way that doesn't depend on knowing the names of the colors.

```
fun <- function(color, DF, col1, col2){
  2L - (color == DF[[col1]] & color == DF[[col2]])
}

cols1 <- unique(df1$color_1)
cbind(df1, sapply(cols1, fun, df1, 'color_1', 'color_2'))
#  combination color_1 color_2 red blue
#1         1_1     red     red   1    2
#2         1_2     red    blue   2    2
#3         1_3     red   green   2    2
#4         1_4     red  yellow   2    2
#5         2_1    blue     red   2    2
#6         2_2    blue    blue   2    1
#7         2_3    blue   green   2    2
#8         2_4    blue  yellow   2    2
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
combination  color_1  color_2
1_1          red       red
1_2          red       blue
1_3          red       green
1_4          red       yellow
2_1          blue      red
2_2          blue      blue
2_3          blue      green
2_4          blue      yellow
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```